# First order differential equation, separable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $g(x)$ is continuous on $[1,2]$ such that $g(1)=0$ and $$g'(x)x^2=\sqrt{1-g^2(x)}$$
>   Find $g(2)$.

I found that $g(x)=\sin(c-\frac{1}{x})$ and since $g(1) = 0$ shouldn't my $c$ be equal to 1, so that $\sin(1-1)=0$.

But when I try for $g(2)$ with $c=1$, I am getting a different answer from the textbook.

Comment: What do you get, and what does the textbook get? (and have you both remembered that angles are measured in radians, not degrees?)

Comment: I got the same solution for the ode.

Comment: The book says g(2) is pi/6,, I might be forgetting something simple bcs im not getting that.

Comment: @Infodayne: Regarding to what Gerry noted you, when $g(1)=0$ so $\sin(c-1)=0$ and then you get $c-1=k\pi$ not$c=1$. If you got this step correctly, then another finial step would be $g(2)=\sin(k\pi+1-1/2)=\sin(k\pi+1/2)$. Isn't this the same answer as in your text book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution, I mean one parameter family of solutions, are correct. Indeed $$g(y)=\sin\left(\frac{-1}x+c\right)$$ Now if we are given $g(1)=0$ so $$0=g(1)=\sin\left(\frac{-1}1+c\right)=\sin(c-1)$$ and then $c=1+k\pi,~~~k\in\mathbb Z$. Hence $$g(2)=\sin(-1/2+c)=\sin(1/2+k\pi),~~~k\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Which is not $\pi/6$, which is what OP says is in the book. I note that $\arcsin(1/2)=\pi/6$, which may be the source of confusion.

Comment: Well done! +1 :)